# use the lazyobject in python or django

Tags: python, django

Looking in `django.utils.functional` I noticed a `LazyObject` class, django uses it in `django.conf`:

```
class LazySettings(LazyObject):
```

it is the defination of `LazyObject`:

```
class LazyObject(object):
    """
    A wrapper for another class that can be used to delay instantiation of the
    wrapped class.

    By subclassing, you have the opportunity to intercept and alter the
    instantiation. If you don't need to do that, use SimpleLazyObject.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._wrapped = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self._wrapped is None:
            self._setup()
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "_wrapped":
            # Assign to __dict__ to avoid infinite __setattr__ loops.
            self.__dict__["_wrapped"] = value
        else:
            if self._wrapped is None:
                self._setup()
            setattr(self._wrapped, name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name == "_wrapped":
            raise TypeError("can't delete _wrapped.")
        if self._wrapped is None:
            self._setup()
        delattr(self._wrapped, name)

    def _setup(self):
        """
        Must be implemented by subclasses to initialise the wrapped object.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    # introspection support:
    __members__ = property(lambda self: self.__dir__())

    def __dir__(self):
        if self._wrapped is None:
            self._setup()
        return  dir(self._wrapped)
```

i want to know what is the best situation to use the `LazyObject`?

Comment: It's like the force.  When you need it, you'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It based on exp. As I know:
1. Get a data and you do not use it now and still operate it, like QuerySet in django
2. A data u can tell where to load/read it now, like configuration.
3. proxy
4. Large set of data and just use part on it now.
And more...

Comment: can you tell me the superiority to use like this in detail?

Comment: 1. queryset, u do not know what data to get at that time, for example: uses = User.object.all() and u use pagation, the real data is not all(), it's like filter(id__gt=xx,id__lt=xx).  2. configutaion can be dynamic resolve in runtime, u do not know it when it not be used.  3. it's proxy design pattern.  4. load large data in one time really slow, so u need to load part by part, like sql, a result row in once.